# Concatenating two std::vector -- which method is more efficient and how/why?

Tags: c++, performance, concatenation, stdvector

Consider the following scenario:

```
std::vector<int> A;
std::vector<int> B;
std::vector<int> AB;
```

I want `AB` to have contents of `A` and then the contents of `B` in the same order.

**Approach 1:**

```
AB.reserve( A.size() + B.size() ); // preallocate memory
AB.insert( AB.end(), A.begin(), A.end() );
AB.insert( AB.end(), B.begin(), B.end() );
```

**Approach 2:**

```
std::vector<int> AB ( A.begin(), A.end() ); // calling constructor
AB.insert ( AB.end(), B.begin(), B.end() );
```

Which one of the above methods is more efficient? Why?
Is there a different method that is more efficient?

Comment: Have you tried measuring it?

Comment: Well it depends massively on the size of both vectors and the implementation of the vector allocator algorithm

Comment: Not sure if you've checked but remember that performance is something you should only concern yourself with once you've established it's a _problem._ Unless your vectors are massive, or the items within them are costly to construct/copy, you won't notice much of a difference. Don't spend a lot of time reducing an 0.2ms operation down to 0.1ms unless you need to do it thousands of times per second :-)

Comment: If performance is not an issue I would suggest you pick the one that is easier to read for you. Readability of code very important once you come back to your code after a long while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first one will always be faster than the second one because it will only perform one memory allocation and the second one will probably have to reallocate at least once. But [my measurements](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91635bd20cea8834) seem to indicate that for sizes less than about 100,000 this is even faster:

```
std::vector<int> AB(A.size() + B.size());
std::copy(A.begin(), A.end(), AB.begin());
std::copy(B.begin(), B.end(), AB.begin() + B.size());
```

I'm guessing this is because, not only does this only perform one allocation and no reallocation, it doesn't even need to check if it should do any reallocation. The downside is it *may* have to zero out all the memory initially, but I think CPUs are good at that.

Comment: *the downside is that it has to zero out all the memory* -- I looked at the generated assembly and I cannot explain such a huge difference, but what is obvious is that the optimizer removed the zeroing out of the memory. The basic generated code for the first and your flavor is the same, but the code is structured in a slightly different way, it looks like the optimizer was better prepared to handle this last option...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Interesting. This is not the first time I've been surprised how well a "zero-out the memory and overwrite" approach has compared to a "reserve the memory and insert" approach. E.g `std::vector<int> A(size); for(size_t i=0;i!=size;++i) A[i]=func(i);` [performs surprisingly well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/deef69909146f580). And maybe you are right, the reason is that the optimizer removes the zeroing out of the memory.

Answer (score 8):

The first one is probably a bit more efficient since you can guarantee that only one memory allocation will be performed. In the second one, chances are (most implementations do) that an allocation for `A.size()` will be done during the vector construction and then the `insert` will trigger a second allocation as it needs to grow by `B.size()` elements.

Answer (score 3):

Approach 1 performs *no* reallocations, while Approach 2 may reallocate several times, and will in practice most likely reallocate once. So Approach 1 is better.

Comment: The iterator range being inserted uses RandomAccessIterators, so the number of elements being inserted can be counted in O(1) and so there is no excuse for reallocating more than once in approach 2.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Is that actually guaranteed, or just a common implementation? (I know there's an actual guarantee for the range constructor.)

Comment: @KerrekSB: It is one of those things that would be considered a bug even if the standard does not guarantee it.

Comment: It's not guaranteed, but that's why I said "no excuse" rather than "it 's a bug if it reallocates" :-) You should definitely complain to your vendor if their implementation doesn't count the elements when inserting RandomAccessIterators. The vector constructor taking an iterator range is _required_ to count the elements for anything except InputIterators, but the range `insert` isn't.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I complain to my vendor all the time :-)